# Arba'a Ushmonim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred eighty-four?

### ?ארבעה ושמונים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 284.

I don't know if it's worth chasing after a lazy gematria for this one.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred eighty-three entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: I have list of about 60-70 Gimtariot with that number, it's actually a book. Do you have any preferences to the subject?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

284 is the most verses read on one regular shabbat.

- Mattot  112
- Ma'asei 132
- Maftir  3
- Haftora 26
- Mincha  11
- TOTAL   284

Comment: +1. Nice! Although it actually depends on minhag; Sephardim and some chassidim make the haftarah 27 pesukim long, because they conclude with Jer. 4:1-2 instead of 3:4.

Comment: @Alex Yes, that was my answer for next time!!

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105700/170

Comment: This assumes "regular shabbat" excludes Shabbat Rosh Chodesh

Answer (score 6):

יח  כָּל-הַלְוִיִּם בְּעִיר הַקֹּדֶשׁ, מָאתַיִם שְׁמֹנִים וְאַרְבָּעָה

[Nehemiah 11:18](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%97) says there are 284 leviem in Jerusalem at that time.

Answer (score 4):

Bavel בבל is mentioned 284 times in Tanach.

Answer (score 1):

Yaakov sent 220 goats to Eisav and kept **284** for himself, because these pair of numbers are a special class of numbers known as amicable numbers which the ancients knew gained the love of the one the gift was sent to, and through this Yaakov tried to gain Eisav’s affection.

This is discussed in detail in [this post](http://cheshbon.weeklyshtikle.com/2010/11/goats-and-amicable-numbers.html).

Comment: Where are those numbers found? Discussing how it's derived from the pessukim (also, what "[amicable numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers)" are) would improve this post. +1

Comment: @Shokhet - For the Mi Yodeya series I have included enough info. in the answer. All the details can be found in the link and including then here would be tediously excessive.