# Chamisha Ushmonim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred eighty-five?

### ?חמישה ושמונים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 285.

The best lazy gematria I can come up with for this one is weak, but that's no reason to be cowed.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred eighty-four entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Alex correctly noted here [Arba'a Ushmonim Umatayim - mi yodeya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12394/arbaa-ushmonim-umatayim-mi-yodeya/12404#12404) 285 is the most psukim read on a regular shabbat in sefard/chassidishe shuls:

- Mattot  112
- Ma'asei 132
- Maftir  3
- Haftora 27
- Mincha  11
- TOTAL   285

Note the longer haftorah than the previous answer.

Answer (score 3):

The first translation of the Hebrew Bible was written in Greek.  This began in 285 BCE

Comment: Is that a good thing? x_X

Comment: @Naftali I don't think so, but it is an important part of Jewish History.  It molded so much  even through today.

Comment: That is true. ..

Comment: However it is the non Jewish date.

Comment: @Gershon: I think there've been a couple other entries in this series where people have used the non-Jewish date for lack of any more interesting fact.

Answer (score 2):

Gimtaria "El Rahum (Merciful God)."