# Echad Vetish'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred ninety-one?

### ?אחד ותשעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 291.

I'll bet you can land something interesting from the lazy gematria this time.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred ninety entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

291 is the gematria malei (the combined gematria of all the names of the letters spelled out) of Elohim. [See here](http://members.home.nl/frankcolijn/frankcolijn/de_ale3.gif) and [here](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%A5_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%93).

Comment: -1: I dislike unsourced _gimatriyaos_ as answers in this series. (Every word has a _gimatriya_; we can do this all day. Usually there's nothing special about the _gimatriya_ in question (which would be mentioned in a source).)

Comment: @msh210, it's in [Pri Eitz Chaim, Shaar HaZemiros 4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%A5_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%93): הריעו, גי' רצ"א, שהוא אלהים דאלפין - "the word הריעו equals 291, which is the Name אלקים with [the *hei* spelled out] with an *alef*."

Answer (score 3):

There are 14 possible Jewish calendar combinations. In a year where the following combination happens  - בח"ג - there are **291** days that are not Shabbos or Yom Tov (Chutz L'Aretz) and you may do Melacha.

An explanation of what בח"ג mean.

- The first letter is the day of the week that Rosh HaShana comes out on.
- The second letter tells you whether Cheshvon and Kisleiv have both 29 days = (ח) for Chasair. If Cheshvon has 29 days and Kisleiv has 30 days then = (כ) for K'Sidran. If both Chesvan and Kisleiv have 30 days then = (ש) for Shlaima.
- The third letter is the day of the week that Pesach comes out on.

Answer (score 1):

in the year 291 BCE the Septuagint was created, and while this is not exactly a Jewish book (although it was translated by Jews) it had a major effect on Judaism to this day.

Comment: 291? Wasn't it done under the sponsorship of [Ptolemy II Philadelphus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy_II_Philadelphus), who began his sole rule c. 283?

Comment: Contradiction? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12529/759

Answer (score 1):

291 years from *Ever*'s birth to *Yitzchak*'s.