# Most Torah verses read on one Shabbat

Tags: torah-reading, statistics

The double Parashah of Mattot-Masei has 244 verses. Is there another occasion during the year when more verses are read on single day?

Comment: There is a Minhag to read all of sefer Devarim from a Sefer Torah on Hoshana Rabbah. Also the reading of sefer Devarim by the King during Hakhel.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12404/759 But Vayakhel-Pekudei-Hachodesh is longer in terms of words.

Comment: @Silver Hakhel and Hoshana Rabba don't happen on Shabbat.

Comment: @DoubleAA I know, the title says "Shabbat", but the question says "is there another occasion" so I thought it was worth a comment

Comment: On simchas Torah the first Aliyah of B’reishis is read 10’s of times in many shuls .

Comment: I recommend that you clarify that your referring specifically to a Shabbat reading. That's my understanding. I think the combination of Vayakhel-Pekudei together with the parshat Hachodesh reading (which almost always occurs on that Shabbat in a non-leap year) significantly exceeds the Matot-Masei combo. I have to re-check this.

Comment: See my answer. You picked the longest, IMO. If you're a Torah reader, as I am, prepare yourself a big cup of H2O and make sure the shul's AC works extremely well. Or, be in Israel, this year and you won't have to worry about this.

Comment: Yes, if there would be a groom present and the designated portion in Haye Sara is read then all combined would surpass all other readings during the year.

Comment: @Oliver you seem to mention a minhag. Please explain this and perhaps, post as an answer. I have no clue about this minhag.

Comment: @DanF no idea? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80903/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Oh snap. Ihu ka mosiv leh ve’ihu ka mefarek leh.

Answer (score 1):

Matot-Masei is the longest Shabbat reading in terms of verses. Matot is 112 verses and Masei is 132 verses (most of them short ones near the beginning of the parsha, so they add significantly to the "bulk.") In total you have 244 verses.

I initially thought that Vayakhel-Pekudei occurring on Shabbat Rosh Hodesh which is also SHabbat Hachodesh in a non-leap year (as it was last year) was more. But, alas, even with reading from 3 Sifrei Torah, they total 241 verses - definitely the 2nd longest!

So, if you're referring to what might be read specifically on a Shabbat, the answer is "No", unless you want to account for multiple readings of Vezot Habracha when Simchat Torah occurs on Shabbat in Israel. Then, that total is unknown.

Comment: If we're counting multiple readings we can also count Mattot-Masei in a synagogue that also has a Hashkama Minyan.

Comment: @DoubleAA Somehow, you have an unintentional habit of making me feel bad. One year, I foolishly, volunteered to do a haskama minyan in another shul, that week in addition to my "regular" duties in my regular weekly shul. I love laining and I really have great love for the Torah, you know. But, not this way!